Hechsher: Magen David with word "Kosher"
Does anyone recognize a hechsher consisting of a magen david with the word "kosher" on the right, set in a faux Hebrew typeface, surrounded by a rectangle with rounded corners?  See it, for example, at https://www.amazon.com/Rani-Farina-Coarse-Natural-NON-GMO/dp/B07G8R7NZC/


The font and style seems similar to https://www.ksakosher.org/about-ksa/

It looks like that's not the mark of any kosher-certifying agency, but just the company's own unvetted assertion that its products are kosher. The logo is on another product from the same brand with this Q & A:

Q: Are Rani Brand Spices Kosher?
A: Yes and No. All of our products are inherently kosher, though it
does not have a specific kosher company designation. Our company does
not process any dairy or meat products whatsoever.

